# Linux Device Driver Major number allocation

Tags: linux-device-driver

What are the specific cases where static allocation of major numbers are required(i.e the necessity to create device nodes in advance) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static allocation of major numbers is usually used for most common devices. A list of those devices can be found in Documentation/devices.txt within the kernel source tree.

If you're developing a driver for your own use you can use static assigning as long as you use a number that appears to be unused. But if your driver will be deployed more widely picking a random number and assigning it like this can eventually cause conflicts, so it might be better to use dynamic allocation.

[Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/)